# Storing password in an AES container

Tags: aes, password-storage

I know about storing passwords as salted hashes and I know it is even safe enough for Linux.
But even before I knew this, I was wondering if it is safe to store a password in an AES container encrypted with the password itself.

In case my question got incomprehensible, some pythonish pseudo code:

```
AES(data=password, key=password)
```

Comment: This question belongs on security.stackexchange.com, not here. Cryptography is a specialist subject, which unlike regular programming cannot always be verified through simple experiments; DO NOT trust regular programmers to answer cryptography questions correctly.

Comment: @RobinGreen It actually belongs on http://crypto.stackexchange.com. Note that there are a few crypto people on this forum :P

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not as safe as using a Password Based Key Derivation Function. The most important issue with passwords are dictionary and brute force attacks - trying passwords, in other words. Now the outcome of `AES(data=password, key=password)` is always the same value (as the calculation does not contain any salt). This means that building a rainbow table is possible. Furthermore, AES is a very fast, so it is very easy for attackers to check many passwords.

So you are much better off using a PBKDF such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt, with a high iteration count and at least 64 bits of random salt.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732232/rc4-safe-to-use-plaintext-as-the-key-to-encrypt-itself, where I describe essentially the same thing for RC4 rather than AES. In order to make this scheme secure, it would need to be `AES(data=password, key=PBKDF(password))`, which just adds a useless step on top of `PBKDF(password)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question Schnuss? If it does, please hit the V mark to the left to accept, otherwise indicate what is missing from the answer.